How to reference ILogger in C# winforms application
Below is the code I have added to the Program.cs file in my code.  What I want to be able to do is write a log message from any one of the forms in my application.  Would prefer to write it to a .log file in the same directory as the application but for now I just need to figure out how to reference this ILogger object to write any message from another class module within the application.
It seems like I need to create an instance of the ILogger to write to it but I cannot find an example of how to do that after hours of googling ILogger examples.  All I can find is the same code that I have below with no explanation on how to reference these objects.  Any help would be appreciated.
// customized ILoggerProvider writes logs to text files 
    public class CustomFileLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider
{
    private readonly StreamWriter _logFileWriter;

    public CustomFileLoggerProvider(StreamWriter logFileWriter)
    {
        _logFileWriter = logFileWriter ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logFileWriter));
    }

    public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
    {
        return new CustomFileLogger(categoryName, _logFileWriter);

    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _logFileWriter?.Dispose();
    }
}

public class CustomFileLogger : ILogger
{
    private readonly string _categoryName;
    private readonly StreamWriter _logFileWriter;

    public CustomFileLogger (string categoryName, StreamWriter logFileWriter)
    {
        _categoryName = categoryName;
        _logFileWriter = _logFileWriter;

    }

    public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public bool IsEnabled (LogLevel logLevel)
    {
        return logLevel >= LogLevel.Information;
    }

    public void Log<TState> (LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, 
        TState state, 
        Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
    {
        if (!IsEnabled(logLevel))
        {
            return;
        }

        // get the formatted log message 
        var message = formatter(state, exception);

        // write log messages to text file 
        _logFileWriter.WriteLine($"[{logLevel}] [{_categoryName}] {message}");
        _logFileWriter.Flush();

    }

    
}

Here is the code that I added to the constructor of my class.  It compiles OK but does not seem to write any logs anywhere.
 // set up logging 
 using (StreamWriter logFileWriter = new StreamWriter(logFilePath, append: true))
 {
     ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
     {
         builder.AddProvider(new CustomFileLoggerProvider(logFileWriter));
     });

     ILogger logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("Information");

     using (logger.BeginScope("[scope is enabled]"))
     {
         logger.LogInformation("clsJob instance created");
     }


 }


Why that custom implementation? You can use the default Microsoft logging abstractions and inject ILogger into your classes. If you need targets not provided by ms then you out for a different backend like Serilog or NLog or log4net.

Have a look into this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logging

And this,  too : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-8.0

so do I just put this code everywhere that I want to write to the log?  I was hoping to create a logging object that I could just reference and not have to have new objects in every class object.       using ILoggerFactory factory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => builder.AddConsole());
ILogger logger = factory.CreateLogger();
logger.LogInformation("Hello World! Logging is {Description}.", "fun");

how do I use this on a WinForms application?  The Console is not recognized when I try to reference it

it appears there is something that has changed with the ILoggerFactory and while it requires a reference to the Console it is no longer included in the library or something.  One person said you have to add an explicit reference to the console() method but I do not see that in the available references so maybe it has to be downloaded separately now.  Anyway, I'm just going to go back to logging in a text file and wait until they get this ILogger busiiness corrected
